# q2q protocol specification

Tags: protocols

Where can I find a complete specification of the q2q protocol? I wanna try implementing it on my own also to see difference between q2q and p2p but I can't find a complete documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks (to me) like Q2Q is just a term for the data transmission scheme[1] implemented by Vertex. And as vertex is work in progress, it is a moving target.

A good bet is to have a look at the current implementation:
http://buildbot.divmod.org/apidocs/vertex.q2q.html

[1] I am reluctant to call it a protocol until we actually unearth a specification for it. ;)

Comment: Maybe you're right. I don't feel like scrolling to the current implementation though. I'll just stick with p2p for now.